# League table sorting to get the player rank

Tags: php

I am trying to find the record of the player based on the score. If two players are tied on score then player who played few games is ranked top. If two players are tied on score and number of games played, then the player who was first in the list of players is ranked higher.

This is the code so far I have tried.

```
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca5f93990e1cb6a69bbbd734afde32f1ffa51522
```

But the answer I am getting is not correct.

```
   <?php
    class LeagueTable
    {
        public function __construct($players)
        {
            $this->standings = array();
            foreach($players as $index => $p)
            {
                $this->standings[$p] = array
                (
                    'index' => $index,
                    'games_played' => 0, 
                    'score' => 0
                );
            }
        }

    public function recordResult($player, $score)
    {
        $this->standings[$player]['games_played']++;
        $this->standings[$player]['score'] += $score;
    }

    public function playerRank($rank)
    {
        $ranks = $this->standings;
        uasort($ranks, function ($a, $b) {
            if ($a['score'] >= $b['score']) {
                if ($a['score'] == $b['score']) {
                    if ($a['games_played'] >= $b['games_played']) {
                        if ($a['games_played'] == $b['games_played']) {
                            return $a['index'] > $b['index'];
                        } else {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });

        print_r($this->standings);
    }
}

$table = new LeagueTable(array('Mike', 'Chris', 'Arnold'));
$table->recordResult('Mike', 2);
$table->recordResult('Mike', 3);
$table->recordResult('Arnold', 5);
$table->recordResult('Chris', 5);
echo $table->playerRank(1);
```

### Result

```
  I am getting Array 
    ( 
        [Mike] => Array 
            ( 
                [index] => 0 
                [games_played] => 2 
                [score] => 5 
            ) 

        [Chris] => Array 
            ( 
                [index] => 1 
                [games_played] => 1 
                [score] => 5 
            ) 

        [Arnold] => Array 
            ( 
                [index] => 2 
                [games_played] => 1 
                [score] => 5 
            ) 

    )  BUT my test says Example case: Wrong answer 
      Players have different scores: Wrong answer 
      Players tied by score: Wrong answer 
      Players tied by games played: Wrong answer
```

Comment: What answer are you getting? Please indicate.

Comment: @Wreigh I have update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function will do what you want. The tricky part is that the you want the player with the *highest* score or the *lowest* number of games played or the *lowest* index. So the condition for each test in the sort is different for `games_played` and `index` than it is for `score`. After sorting we return the key associated with the `$rank` variable, remembering that ranking starts with 1 but the array of keys starts at 0, so we have to subtract one from `$rank`.

```
public function playerRank($rank)
{
    $ranks = $this->standings;
    uasort($ranks, function ($a, $b) {
        // sort by score
        if ($a['score'] != $b['score']) 
            return ($a['score'] > $b['score']) ? -1 : 1;
        // equal! sort by games played
        if ($a['games_played'] != $b['games_played'])
            return ($a['games_played'] < $b['games_played']) ? -1 : 1;
        // equal! sort by index
        return ($a['index'] < $b['index']) ? -1 : 1;
    });

    return array_keys($ranks)[$rank-1];
}
```

I have tested this code at https://www.testdome.com/questions/php/league-table/15401?visibility=1 and it passes all tests.

Answer (score 1):

uasort needs to return 0, -1, or 1. I've also rearranged a little bit. You also need to return the player and the end using the `$rank` sent.

```
public function playerRank($rank) {
    // sort standings
    uasort($this->standings, function ($a, $b) {
        if($a['score'] == $b['score']) {
            if($a['games_played'] == $b['games_played']) {
                if($a['index'] == $b['index']) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return $a['index'] < $b['index'] ? -1 : 1;
            }
            return $a['games_played'] < $b['games_played'] ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return $a['score'] < $b['score'] ? -1 : 1;
    });
    // return player at rank
    return print_r($this->standing[$rank], 1);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I missed a level. One sec

Comment: https://www.testdome.com/questions/php/league-table/15401?visibility=1. I am not getting the answer

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the php function array multisort()

http://www.php.net/array_multisort

```
<?php
    class LeagueTable
    {
        public function __construct($players)
        {
            $this->standings = array();
            foreach($players as $index => $p)
            {
                $this->standings[$p] = array
                (
                    'index' => $index,
                    'games_played' => 0, 
                    'score' => 0
                );
            }
        }

    public function recordResult($player, $score)
    {
        $this->standings[$player]['games_played']++;
        $this->standings[$player]['score'] += $score;
    }


    public function playerRank()
    {
        $data = $this->standings;


        array_multisort(array_column($data, 'score'),  SORT_DESC,
                array_column($data, 'games_played'), SORT_ASC,
                array_column($data, 'index'), SORT_ASC,
                $data);

        print_r($data);
    }
}

$table = new LeagueTable(array('Mike', 'Chris', 'Arnold'));
$table->recordResult('Mike', 2);
$table->recordResult('Mike', 3);
$table->recordResult('Arnold', 5);
$table->recordResult('Chris', 5);
echo $table->playerRank();
```

Comment: I find that multisort is a bit cleaner.

Comment: @cecilmerrelakabringrainfire That is simple (and simple is **good**) but this line from the manual concerns me as to whether it will always correctly resolve the situation where the scores and games played are the same: "If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted array is undefined"

Comment: @Nick In the case that two are equal, it will fall back to sorting by the index number in the array.

Comment: @cecilmerrelakabringrainfire the manual doesn't mention anything about resorting to sorting by the index number...

Comment: @Nick I guess I've never noticed it before, it'll group all the same values together with indexes unordered. with multisort, you can define an index column along with the other args like so, array_column($data, 'index'),  SORT_DESC,

Comment: @cecilmerrelakabringrainfire that ought to do it although you want to sort index ASC so that it sorts in the same direction as games_played (lower is better). You should update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the array_multisort() function i improved the answer a little bit and 
I have tested this code at 
https://www.testdome.com/questions/php/league-table/15401?visibility=1 and it passes all tests.

```
   public function playerRank(int $rank) : string
    {

        $data = $this->standings;
        $sorted_data=[];

        array_multisort(
                array_column($data, 'score'),  SORT_DESC,
                array_column($data, 'games_played'), SORT_ASC,
                array_column($data, 'index'), SORT_ASC,
                $data);

         $current_rank = 1;
         foreach($data as $player_name => $value)
         {
            $sorted_data['rank'] = $current_rank;
            $sorted_data[$current_rank]['name'] = $player_name;
            $current_rank++;
         }

    return $sorted_data[strval($rank)]["name"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class LeagueTable
{
    public function __construct($players)
    {
        $this->standings = array();
        foreach($players as $index => $p)
        {
            $this->standings[$p] = array
            (
                'index' => $index,
                'games_played' => 0, 
                'score' => 0
            );
        }
    }
        
    public function recordResult($player, $score)
    {
        $this->standings[$player]['games_played']++;
        $this->standings[$player]['score'] += $score;
    }
    
    public function playerRank($rank)
    {
        $ranks = $this->standings;
        uasort($ranks, function ($a, $b) {
          // sort by score
          if ($a['score'] != $b['score']) 
            return ($a['score'] > $b['score']) ? -1 : 1;
          // equal! sort by games played
          if ($a['games_played'] != $b['games_played'])
            return ($a['games_played'] < $b['games_played']) ? -1 : 1;
          // equal! sort by index
          return ($a['index'] < $b['index']) ? -1 : 1;
        });

      return array_keys($ranks)[$rank-1];
    }
}
      
$table = new LeagueTable(array('Mike', 'Chris', 'Arnold'));
$table->recordResult('Mike', 2);
$table->recordResult('Mike', 3);
$table->recordResult('Arnold', 5);
$table->recordResult('Chris', 5);
echo $table->playerRank(1);
```